# location and name of PCI Core C file(s) in Linux kernel source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pci

I like to take a look at PCI core C file(s) in Linux kernel source. Can anyone please let me know. I need especially the code where PCI core C file(s) exists. I know most of the kernel is made up of Drivers but where are the codes for PCI core and other core code like USB core.

Thank for help

Comment: You didn't think to look in `/drivers/pci`?

Comment: PCI core and controllers: _drivers/pci_, USB core: _drivers/usb/core_.